# angular.js - set width and height of farbricjs canvas from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fabricjs

I have to change my `fabric.js` canvas size inside my app. I have this defined in my `controller.js` :

```
kitchensink.controller('CanvasControls', function ($scope) {

    $scope.canvas = canvas;
    $scope.getActiveStyle = getActiveStyle;

    addAccessors($scope);
    watchCanvas($scope);

    // Editing Canvas Size
    // ================================================================

    $scope.setCanvasSize = function () {
        console.log('Resizing now...');
        canvas.setWidth(presetSizes.width);
        canvas.setHeight(presetSizes.height);
        canvas.calcOffset();
    };

    $scope.presetSizes = [
        {
            name: 'iPad Landscape',
            height: 768,
            width: 1024
            },
        {
            name: 'iPad Portrait',
            height: 1024,
            width: 766
            },
        {
            name: 'iPad Pro Landscape',
            height: 1024,
            width: 1366
            },
        {
            name: 'iPad Pro Portrait',
            height: 1366,
            width: 1024
            }
        ];


})
```

I am trying to set my canvas size in my index.html with ng-click like this:

```
<x-menu>
    <x-menuitem value="no_bg" ng-click='setCanvasSize(size.width, size.height)' ng-repeat='size in presetSizes' selected="true">
        <x-label>{{ size.name }}</x-label>
    </x-menuitem>
</x-menu>
```

I am getting the array with `{{ size.name }}`  but I am doing obviously something wrong for setting / getting the width and height...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have parameters for the width and height in the `setCanvasSize()`

Next to that the what is `presetSizes.width`? I dont see this variable in your controller. If you mean `$scope.presetSizes` wich is a array you need to access the `height` and `width` through an `index` like `$scope.presetSizes[0].width`

try changing you `$scope.setCanvasSize = function ()` to `$scope.setCanvasSize = function (width, height)` or `$scope.setCanvasSize = function (index)` 
and use it like

```
$scope.setCanvasSize = function (index) {
    console.log('Resizing now...');
    canvas.setWidth($scope.presetSizes[index].width);
    canvas.setHeight($scope.presetSizes[index].height);
    canvas.calcOffset();
};
//This one suits your question
$scope.setCanvasSize = function (width, height) {
    console.log('Resizing now...');
    canvas.setWidth(width);
    canvas.setHeight(height);
    canvas.calcOffset();
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jordy! Working like a charme. I see how much I have to learn :-)